# Intellij - issue java heap space when running a webapp

Tags: intellij-idea, jvm

I am working with Intellij and a JEE maven web application for years.

Everything used to work fine until this morning.

When I package my webapp with Maven, I have no issue.

When I run my webapp with Intellij I am getting this error :

> Error:maven-resources-test:rh-myapp: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java
>   heap space

I don't understand why (I haven't changed any JVM options).

Thank you.

[image]

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Kcd.png)

Comment: `When I run my webapp with Intellij I am getting this error` Please add screenshot of Run/Debug Configuration you are using to run the app and screenshot of the error.

Comment: Try adding more memory in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | **Build process heap size (Mbytes)** and/or Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner | **VM Options**.

Comment: I have done both settings changement, it doesn't solve the issue. Strange thing is that if I run a mvn package, I don't have any problem. The issue only occurs when I run/debug the webapp. And if I run the task maven-resources-test I don't have the problem.

Comment: mvn package runs Maven, Run/Debug runs a build by IntelliJ itself. Report a bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: I have upgraded intellij, now it works......